# Vuetify VSelect children are not displayed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create Vuetify VSelect for category tree where category object has children array as prop.

```html
<VSelect
    v-model="selectedCategory"
    :label="label"
    outlined
    :items="categories"
    clearable
    :itemChildren="item => item?.children ?? []"
    :itemTitle="item => item?.name ?? noDataLabel"
  />
```

Category object is type of

```
type CategoryInput = {
  children: Array<CategoryInput>;
  description?: InputMaybe<string>;
  id?: InputMaybe<number>;
  name: string
  parentId?: InputMaybe<number>;
  visible: boolean;
}
```

As result I have only root categories.
Do you have any idea what could be wrong or what I missed?

Comment: Prop doesn't look implemented.  Try directly reporting the issue to the Vuetify team on their [github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues)

Comment: Sounds weird, why something not implemented could be added to documentation? [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/18939)
How did you check it if I may know?